# asp.net mvc - how to enforce controller layer supertype

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, controller

I'd like to use a class extending `Controller` as the default base type for controllers in my project, as opposed to using `Controller` itself. So, I would be doing this:

```
public class FooController : MyBaseController
```

Is there a way I can enforce this, so that people cannot create controllers which extend `Controller` directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

However I prefer the unit testing approach [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982481/asp-net-mvc-how-to-enforce-controller-layer-supertype/6982771#6982771) here is another one by using a custom controller factory.

```
public class MyControllerFactory<T> : DefaultControllerFactory where T : Controller
{
    #region Overrides of DefaultControllerFactory

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(controllerType))
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

You can set it up in the application start method of your Global.asax like this:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyControllerFactory<MyBaseController>());
```

This of course causes a runtime exception when not deriving from `MyBaseController` which may not be suitable in your current scenario.

Comment: Voted the other answers down and this one up because its the most fool proof answer and doesn't require any additional involvement during development time.

Answer (score 6):

You can always create a unit test that (via reflection) retrieves all classes that derive from `Controller` and asserts that each class is also a subclass of `MyBaseController`.  It would be along the lines of

```
[TestMethod]
public class All_Controllers_Derive_From_MyBaseController()
{
    // Act
    var controllerTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                                   .GetAssemblies()
                                   .SelectMany(asm => asm.GetTypes())
                                   .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Controller))
                                   .ToList();

   // Verify
   foreach (var type in controllerTypes)
   {
        // Make sure the type isn't the actual controller type
        if (type is Controller)
            continue;

        Assert.IsTrue(type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MyBaseController)), 
                           string.Format("{0} is not a subclass of the MyBaseController class", type.FullName));
   }
}
```

Now if someone creates a controller that doesn't use your base controller your unit tests will fail and tell you which ones are not correct.

Note that this code was written free-hand, so it might need some adjustment but that's the basic idea.

Comment: I like this. At the very least developers are notified of any controllers that break the rule, and any valid exceptions to the rule can be written into the unit tests.

Comment: What does the `if (type is Controller) continue;` bit do?

Comment: It checks if the current type is of MVC's `Controller` type, and if so excludes it from the check.  Obviously MVC's `Controller` class isn't a subclass of your base class.  You might have to add another check for your base controller, I don't remember offhand if `MyBaseController.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MyBaseController))` would be true or false.

Comment: Actually googling shows that it won't, so you will have to add another exception for `if (type is MyBaseController)`.  Also if you question is about the `is` bit, `is` checks if a variable's type is the same as the type on the right hand, and it's functionally equivalent of `if (type.GetType() == typeof(Controller))`

Comment: The reason I asked is I couldn't think of why the code would find any Controller type (as opposed to subclasses), but then you're casting your net wider than just the MVC assembly, so maybe that's why.

Comment: Oh no you are correct, I forgot I did `IsSubclassOf` in the Linq statement.  So that if statement isn't needed.  I need more coffee :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices and both involve writing some code.

**choice #1** You can create a filter and try and catch the error at runtime. You better have good a good user acceptance test process in place to touch all of the pages.

**Choice #2** involves writing a task for MSBuild that checks that each controller class is derived from your specified class. Just load the application assembly (or assemblies) and go to town!

I prefer choice #2. It doesn't affect application runtime performance and gives you better coverage. You can run it at the end of a build.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I want to question your reasons, but here's an answer: One (slightly underhanded) method you could use is to name the base class "Controller" and put it in the same namespace as your individual controllers. As long as people don't specifically extend System.Web.Mvc.Controller, they'll get your Controller class. None the wiser, possibly.

Comment: But there would be a conflict if the controller has a using for System.Web.Mvc, and the developer could explicitly choose the System.Web.Mvc one.

Comment: As for questioning my reasons, you're welcome to. I want to require authentication and handle exceptions in a particular way without remembering to tack filters on. Do you think this is unwise?

Comment: I believe types from the same namespace will be preferred over ones imported with a using statement (disclaimer: I'm a VB programmer; it could be different in C#).

Comment: You're right that developers could still explicitly choose System.Web.Mvc, which is where the reason-questioning comes in. If another developer on the project makes the informed choice that they want to work around your authentication and exception handling, isn't it better to take it up with them in person?

Comment: I should use that argument with my IT guys. If I want to remote onto the server and start mucking around with IIS settings, shouldn't they just take that up with me in person? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the default code generation template, so that it always creates a new controller that inherits from the correct class. The downside is this involves distributing the updated templates to the dev team. See Scott Hanselman's blog for more detailed instructions.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx

Comment: Although not 'enforcing' the base class, this is an excellent suggestion.

Comment: True enough. The unit test approach will work, but it only after the fact. Changing the templates gives the developers the correct inheritance right out of the gate. Probably the best approach would combine the two techniques.